# Upload issue in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload

This is the html part:

```
 <form action ="<?php echo base_url(); ?>home/register_doctor" method ="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8">
...
<input id="file-0" class="file" type="file" multiple data-min-file-count="1" name = "avatar" >
...
</form>
```

This is the the controller part:

```
    public function register_doctor(){
       ...
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
           ....
        }else{
          $this->do_upload();
        }
    }
    function do_upload(){
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/doctors/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '100';
        $config['max_width']  = '1024';
        $config['max_height']  = '768';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->do_upload('avatar');
        $x = $this->upload->display_errors();
        var_dump($x);
    }
```

And the result of this message: `You did not select a file to upload.`. Can someone help me with this ?

**UPDATE** THIS IS THE FOLDER STRUCTURE:
[image]

**UPDATE** THIS IS MY PHP.INI FILE: [CLICK HERE](http://cazare-carei-strand.ro/php/php.txt)

Comment: This is the result of var_dump of $_FILES :  array(0) { }  I put it on the of the function do_upload

Comment: It is: upload_max_filesize=512M in the php.ini

Comment: what is the size of the file you trying to upload?

Comment: The size of the img is:  5.51 KB (5,651 bytes). It is the image that i uploaded on the post

Comment: I uploaded my php ini file on my post. Please check it. I do the upload WITHOUT ajax

Comment: I don't believe that the php ini the problem I do the upload using PHP functions and it works, but the CI functions does not  and I am out of idea. Can you help me ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75031/discussion-between-george-moldovan-and-cristik).

Comment: here is the form: http://cazare-carei-strand.ro/php/form.txt

Comment: @GeorgeMoldovan Moldovan have you checked my answer?

Comment: @RejoanulAlam Yes I do but i got the same message

Answer (score 0):

problem is in config

```
    $config['max_size'] = '100';
    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
    $config['max_height']  = '768';
```

This should be as following

```
    $config['max_size'] = 100;
    $config['max_width']  = 1024;
    $config['max_height']  = 768;
```

hope it will help

Comment: I got the same: You did not select a file to upload. :(

Comment: clear your cache & make sure your directory path is `'./uploads/doctors'`

Comment: is it not weird the result of var_dump($_FILES); is array(0) { }   ? in my function ?

Comment: Check your client side code. Perhaps any code exist which is making your selected file empty when submit

Answer (score 0):

replace your `<form action ="<?php echo base_url(); ?>home/register_doctor" method ="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8">`

to

```
<?php echo  form_open_multipart('home/register_doctor'); ?>
```